# Injecting HTML from background page of a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and would like to inject some HTML code to the DOM in a specific situation (it will result in a message being shown to the user). However - i would like to do this from the background page and not from the content script.  Is this possible? can the background page manipulate the DOM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this script in your background.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: "$('body').prepend('Some html')"
});
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "insert.js"
});
```

Comment: Please note: this is not "without using a content script", since `code` is exactly a content script to be executed. The example also requires jQuery to be pre-injected.

Comment: in first my example you can write pure javascript code. In my extension i use JQuery and thats why my example was with $ sign ))

Comment: Yet, you do not mention it, and your second example just doesn't make sense without any commentary.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly. Instead send a message from your background page to a content script with all required data for the script to create proper HTML code or inject the code using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.